# formData.append is null value in reactjs in uploading file

Tags: reactjs

hi i got a problem when i try to upload an image, the FormData() is return null value inside it, even i already append it

code of uploadhandler

```
  const uploadFileHandler = async (e) => {
const file = e.target.files[0];
const formData = new FormData();
// formData.append("username", "Chris");
formData.append("image", file);

console.log(file);
console.log(formData);
setUploading(true);

try {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  };

  const { data } = await axios.post(
    "/api/v1/uploads/primary",
    formData,
    config
  );
  setImage(data);
  setUploading(false);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  setUploading(false);
}};
```

[image: The file Variable is shown its data]

The file Variable is shown its data but still formData is null and this is the code of form, the user Interface im using React CoreUi Admin and this is the code

```
                <CFormGroup>
              <CLabel
                htmlFor="images"
                style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 15 }}
              >
                Featured Image
              </CLabel>
              <CInput
                style={{ height: "calc(2em + 0.75rem + 2px)" }}
                accept="*"
                type="file"
                id="images"
                placeholder="Choose Featured Images"
                value={image}
                onChange={uploadFileHandler}
              />
              {uploading && (
                <div className="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
                  <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                </div>
              )}
            </CFormGroup>
```

i have try many method but its still the same, i read a formData.append() [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) still not working. idk where the wrong is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this part, with the following:

```
const file = e.target.files[0];
const formData = new FormData();
// formData.append("username", "Chris");
formData.append("image", file);
```

```
 const formData = new FormData();
 const reader = new FileReader();

 if (e.target.files[0]) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
 reader.onload = (readerEvent) => {
 formData.append("image", readerEvent.target.result);
};
```

you call a FileReader to read your file. It reads it as data url, then whenever it is ready it's going to append whatever it has read to your formData

Comment: idk why its return null object this is the code that you suggest https://prnt.sc/1ymti3z, and this is the result of formData https://prnt.sc/1ymtron

Comment: could you provide code sandbox for this particular part of the code?

Comment: The first one is correct. No need to change that part.

Answer (score 1):

Your FormData is not null.

If you want to know what the content of your FormData then you can call `formData.get(key)`

```js
const payload = new FormData()
payload.append('foo', 'bar')

// this will not show your value
console.log(payload) 

// this will show your value
console.log(payload.get('foo'))
```